# Changing hex codes to rgb values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rgb

Can someone explain to me how I would convert a hex code, ex: #FF9C19, to an rgb value, corresponding ex: (255, 156, 25), or the other way around using JavaScript?

I found a post that asked this but it was using python.

Answer (score 4):

1. *Hex* codes use *base 16 (hexadecimal)*, *RGB* uses *base  10 (decimal)*
2. *Hex* codes can be split into 3 bytes which describe red *RR*, green *GG* then blue *BB*, i.e. *#RRGGBB*
3. The *#* for hex isn't always written, or sometimes it may use `0x` or `&h` etc instead (you may need to consider this depending on your envionment)

Putting these together and using a [*RegExp*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to extract the interesting bits and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert from the *String* representation of the *base 16* numbers

```
function hex_to_RGB(hex) {
    var m = hex.match(/^#?([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})$/i);
    return {
        r: parseInt(m[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(m[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(m[3], 16)
    };
}
// ex.
hex_to_RGB('#FF0110') // {r: 255, g: 1, b: 16}
```

When converting in the opposite direction you would use `num.toString(16)` and don't forget to pad the bytes with a `'0'` if they're smaller than *(dec)* `16`

---

If you're starting with an *Integer* `i` which represents your *hex colour*, you can access the *RGB* values using bitwise operations, i.e.

```
var i = 0xFF0110, // 16711952
    rgb = {
        r: (i >> 16) & 0xFF,        // or `(i & 0xFF0000) >> 16`
        g: (i >>  8) & 0xFF,        // or `(i & 0x00FF00) >>  8`
        b:  i        & 0xFF         // or ` i & 0x0000FF       `
    }; // {r: 255, g: 1, b: 16}, same as before
```

Answer (score 3):

A legal hex color can be 3 or 6 characters after the '#', and rgb components

can be  either percentages or numbers between 0 and 255.

```
function hexToRgb(c){
    if(/^#([a-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(c)){
        if(c.length== 4){
            c= '#'+[c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2], c[3], c[3]].join('');
        }
        c= '0x'+c.substring(1);
        return 'rgb('+[(c>>16)&255, (c>>8)&255, c&255].join(',')+')';
    }
    return '';
}

function rgbToHex(rgb){
    var c= rgb.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?%?/g);
    if(c){
        c= c.slice(0, 3).map(function(next){
            var itm= next;
            if(itm.indexOf('%')!= -1){
                itm= Math.round(parseFloat(itm)*2.55);
            }
            if(itm<0) itm= 0;
            if(itm>255) itm= 255;
            itm= Math.round(itm).toString(16);
            if(itm.length== 1) itm= '0'+itm;
            return itm;
        });
        return '#'+c.join('').toLowerCase();
    }
    return '';
}
```